# Using Twitter Bootstrap I cannot copy the text in the active Tab-pane in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, webfonts

I am using standard Twitter-Bootstrap code for nav-tabs - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

All functionality works but in IE9 and IE8 and IE7 browser modes I cannot select and copy any of the text content within the active panel. I can in Opera, Chrome etc.

Text outside the panel can be copied in IE.

I am using webfonts but these can be copied outside the active panel.

Cannot post link as its on locked down dev server. Tested the same on different machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue yesterday.

Eventually found a CSS rule for .tab-content {display:table;} was causing the issue.
I added my own CSS rule to override this, setting .tab-content{display:block;} and this fixed the issue.
I don't know why display:table would do this, but that's how I fixed it...